# Stuck on what to do next in squid proxy set up

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, squid

I've been searching for a relevant squid proxy tutorial for Ubuntu for about 7 hours. I'm so lost on what to do. I just want to create a proxy which needs a user/pass to access it and is fairly secure. I get very confused after this step.
Running this on ubunutu 16.04

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get install squid`
3. `vim /etc/squid/squid.conf`

I change the config to:

```
http_port 3128
cache deny all
hierarchy_stoplist cgi-bin ?

access_log none
cache_store_log none
cache_log /dev/null

refresh_pattern ^ftp: 1440 20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher: 1440 0% 1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0% 0
refresh_pattern . 0 20% 4320

acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1

acl SSL_ports port 1-65535
acl Safe_ports port 1-65535
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
acl siteblacklist dstdomain "/etc/squid/blacklist.acl"
http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager

http_access deny !Safe_ports

http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access deny siteblacklist
auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid3/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwd

auth_param basic children 5
auth_param basic realm Squid proxy-caching web server
auth_param basic credentialsttl 2 hours
acl password proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow localhost
http_access allow password
http_access deny all

forwarded_for off
request_header_access Allow allow all
request_header_access Authorization allow all
request_header_access WWW-Authenticate allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Authorization allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Authenticate allow all
request_header_access Cache-Control allow all
request_header_access Content-Encoding allow all
request_header_access Content-Length allow all
request_header_access Content-Type allow all
request_header_access Date allow all
request_header_access Expires allow all
request_header_access Host allow all
request_header_access If-Modified-Since allow all
request_header_access Last-Modified allow all
request_header_access Location allow all
request_header_access Pragma allow all
request_header_access Accept allow all
request_header_access Accept-Charset allow all
request_header_access Accept-Encoding allow all
request_header_access Accept-Language allow all
request_header_access Content-Language allow all
request_header_access Mime-Version allow all
request_header_access Retry-After allow all
request_header_access Title allow all
request_header_access Connection allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Connection allow all
request_header_access User-Agent allow all
request_header_access Cookie allow all
request_header_access All deny all

visible_hostname CoolProxy
```

Now my question is:

1. How do I create the user authentication?
2. How do I test it on firefox to see if the proxy works
3. Is there any other steps left? I've watched/read so many tutorials and none of them seem to work for me

Or even if someone can just show me the steps (even if its for ubuntu 18+)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @reporter edited my post

Comment: it still off-topic because "Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on https://serverfault.com . "